# Why do I get the warning: Don't dereference a pointer that may be invalid

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

With C++ Core-Guidelines lifetime checking enabled (Visual Studio 2019), the following code produces a warning I don't understand:

```
std::list<std::string> getKeys(const std::map<std::string, int>& entities)
{
   std::list<std::string> rc;
   for (auto const& el : entities)
   {
      rc.push_back(el.first);
   }
   return rc;
}
```

The warning:

```
Don't dereference a pointer that may be invalid: '&el->first'.
'el.std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,int>::first' 
may have been invalidated at line 67* (refers to the for-statement)
```

Can anyone explain why iterating using references to a const collection should lead to an invalid pointer?

Comment: That seems like nonsense, there is nothing in that code that would cause concern about lifetime issues

Comment: Is this an actual compiler message, or from kind of intellisense system or other non-compiler validation or analysis tool?

Comment: It's weird that the warning doesn't match the code.  The warning talks about `&el->first`, but you use `el.first`.  Are you sure this warning is coming from this exact code?

Comment: Looks like a static analysis tool that got way too aggressive. Microsoft's does that regularly.

Comment: the code is fine. The warning is a false positive.

Comment: This is not directly a compiler message. I activated Code Analysis in the project's property page, and triggered "Run Code Analysis on File".

Comment: And yes, the warning comes exactly from this code

Comment: It's a false positive then.  It is probably thinking you are iterating through `rc` as you are adding to it, which is a problem, but not what you are doing.

Comment: What is the problem with adding something to variable rc?

Comment: Actually nothing, I though it was a vector, not a list.  I have no clue now why it thinks there is an issue.  File a bug report with MS.

Comment: Since `rc` is a list, there's nothing wrong with iterating over it and adding to it at the same time (well, it *might* be, depending on how you iterate). It would be a different matter when using `std::vector` where iterators can become invalidated when adding elements.

Comment: which one is line 67?